# adding images and search option in android app

Tags: android, android-layout

i have trouble in adding a search option to list various countries or cities in my timezone app.
also i want to add an image that can be set as a clock widget that displays the time according to the timezone selected from the drop down list..i do not know where to start since i am pretty new to android app development..any ideas to help improve this app will be helpful..

here is the code that i am trying to learn.

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center|top"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtGMTTime"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/current" />       

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtCurrentTime"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".MainActivity" />
</LinearLayout>

<Spinner
android:id="@+id/availableID"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/timezone"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/txtTimeZoneTime"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

followed by the java class code.

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);

spinnerAvailableID = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.availableID);

textTimeZone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timezone);
txtCurrentTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCurrentTime);
txtTimeZoneTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTimeZoneTime);

String[] idArray = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();

sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss");

idAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,idArray);

idAdapter.setDropDownViewResource

(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerAvailableID.setAdapter(idAdapter);

getGMTTime();

spinnerAvailableID
.setOnItemSelectedListener(new 

OnItemSelectedListener() {

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?>parent,View view, int position, longid) {
getGMTTime();
String selectedId = (String) (parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
TimeZone timezone =TimeZone.getTimeZone(selectedId);
String TimeZoneName =timezone.getDisplayName();
int TimeZoneOffset =timezone.getRawOffset()/ (60 * 1000);

int hrs = TimeZoneOffset / 60;
int mins = TimeZoneOffset % 60;

miliSeconds = miliSeconds +timezone.getRawOffset();
resultdate = new Date(miliSeconds);
System.out.println(sdf.format(resultdate));
textTimeZone.setText(TimeZoneName + ": GMT " + hrs + "."+ mins);
txtTimeZoneTime.setText("" +sdf.format(resultdate));
miliSeconds = 0;
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?>arg0) {

}
});

}
private void getGMTTime() {
current = Calendar.getInstance();
txtCurrentTime.setText("" + current.getTime());

miliSeconds = current.getTimeInMillis();

TimeZone tzCurrent = current.getTimeZone();
int offset = tzCurrent.getRawOffset();
if (tzCurrent.inDaylightTime(new Date())) {
offset = offset + tzCurrent.getDSTSavings();
}

miliSeconds = miliSeconds - offset;
resultdate = new Date(miliSeconds);
System.out.println(sdf.format(resultdate));
}
}
```

now where exactly do i add the search bar option and custom clock widget image in this code